# Can an isolated atom have permanent/intrinsic electric dipole moment

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics

I know that when we place an atom in an external electric field than the centre of positive charge and the centre of negative charge of the atom can separate out and thus an atom in an external electric field can have electric dipole moment and it is called induced electric dipole moment.

Is it possible for an isolated atom to have their centre of positive charge and centre of negative charge separated out so that they have some electric dipole moment?

Comment: I want to add to the answers below a little side view that is London dispersion forces can be interpreted as an interaction between $temporary$ dipoles of atoms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some reasons (related to discrete symmetries) why atoms, nuclei, and elementary particles should not have electric dipole moments. However, if some discrete symmetries are violated, such objects might have electric dipole moment. So far, this has not been observed in experiments. I don't feel like providing more details (as it would not be clear where to stop:-)). One can find more details in https://doi.org/10.1142/9789814271738_0015 and references there.